# Kubuntu HDD access problem

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde, storage, dolphin

I've installed Kubuntu 16.04 on a fresh new desktop computer. Almost everything is running smoothly, except the second partition of the computer. Need to clarify that, there is only 2 partitions on that PC. One for root or system installation and another for general storage purpose (347.5 GB). Unfortunately, I can't create and paste any folders or files in that partition. How can I overcome the issue? Please help mates. :)

Comment: Have you remembered to mount the generel purpose partition?
And added the propper line to fstab?

Comment: @KenMollerup thanks for your reply. I've mounted the partition. But how can I added the proper line to fstab? What is proper line?

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission related issue. Found excellent solution from Ubuntu forums. Just after logging into the desired user who you want to give the access enter the following command

```
sudo chown -R username:username /media/username/partitionname
```

This should works like charm.